# catching a file when it arrives in the browser

Tags: javascript, flash, asynchronous, get

Im working on a video player at the moment (a flash one). Before the video starts, the player receives a manifest.f4m file. I would like to detect WHEN this file is requested and WHEN it actually arrives (ie the time for the server to generate it). I really have NO idea how to do it, but it should be possible using javascript because Firebug and even Google Chrome's console timeline are able to detect this "event".

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: What are you doing with this information? Are you debugging performance or do you need to actually do something with that data?

Comment: mainly debugging performance, still my debug view is in JS so it would be cool if I good access it through JS ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's in Flash, Firebug may not pick it up in the Net tab since those calls don't go through the browser's API. You may consider using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It will show you just about everything.

Comment: no actually it DOES show in Firebug (but in an unclear way, with a computed time that is not precisely the one I want). I would like to know the events that trigger it so that I could write a debug console of my own

Comment: and I gave fiddler a try but they only have video tutorials which are only playing audio, and I cant have it working with FF, only with IE (launching it from inside Fiddler) working with chrome though oO

Comment: @Cystack, you can try using the FiddlerHook addon for Firefox: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/addons/fiddlerhook/